# Issue designing google maps app in the application

Tags: android

I have seen the tutorial provided to display google maps here...
**http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html.**

But sadly when i try to extend MapActivity instead of Activity the whole program is getting ruined and showing errors starting from onCreate... Whats the solution and how could i get google maps working in my application???

Comment: We've posted some details and information at [http://www.androidref.com/index.html#MapLocation](http://www.androidref.com/index.html#MapLocation)

Answer (score 0):

Well, including the errors will help to provide you more accurate answers.
The emulator where you are running your application on should support Google APIs and the manifest should include

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```